# would the proof to show that $1/(n+n^2)$ converges to 0 be the same as for $1/n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have started this by doing $\mid1/(n+n^2) - 0\mid< \epsilon$ and I have fixed $\epsilon > 0$ which then leads me to $n+n^2 > 1/\epsilon$ however I'm not sure if I should leave it like that or make it so only 1 stays on that side. I carried on otherwise and left it like that and by the archimedian property chose a value $N$ where $N>1/\epsilon.$ Then for any $n > N$ I have $1/(n+n^2) < 1/N < \epsilon.$

Comment: ' only 1 n stays on that side '

Answer (score 2):

What we could use, if we don't need to use a direct approach, is that

$$\frac1{n+n^2} \le \frac1n$$

and then invoke the squeeze theorem.

Otherwise your way seems fine, from here we can use that

$$n+n^2 >n >\frac1{\epsilon}$$

and then take $N>\frac1{\epsilon}$.

Comment: im trying to use a direct approach to see is this is provable the same way if you prove 1/n , using the squeeze theorem will not be the same way as in most cases you wont use the squeeze theorem to prove 1/n converges to 0. im just wondering is it ok to leave it as n + n^2 or is that not possible ?

Comment: sorry did not see the continued post you made before i typed that comment in

Comment: @Michealsmith Yes indeed after editing I see better your work on that and you are almost done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the proof that $\frac1{n+n^2}$ converges can be very similar to the one that $n$ converges. In fact, it will be even simpler, since, in the original proof, you needed to find an $N$ such that $n>\frac1\epsilon$ for $n>N$, and in this proof, you need to find and $N'$ such that $n+n^2>\frac1\epsilon$ for $n>N'$. Clearly, since $n+n^2>n$, simply taking the same $N'$ as in the original proof would be sufficient, but even smaller values of $N'$ would also work (but are not required).

An alternative way of proving convergence is to use the fact that $$0\leq \frac{1}{n+n^2} \leq \frac 1n$$ and using the squeeze theorem.